# DiscordAPIError 40060: "Interaction has already been acknowledged"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am in a problem where I am experiencing this error and I tried my best to fix this API error.

index.js:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Events, Collection, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');

const client = require('./client.js');
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
    if (interaction.customId === 'myModal') {
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'Your submission was received successfully!' });
    const good = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('good');
    const bot = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('bot');
    client.users.send('821682594830614578', `good: "${good}"
bot: "${bot}" from ${interaction.user.username}`);
    }
});
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
  client.user.setActivity('you or i have no food', { type: ActivityType.Watching });
    console.log(`Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});
client.login(process.env.token);
```

ping.js:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const client = require('./../client.js');
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Ping! Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(`Websocket heartbeat: ${client.ws.ping} ms. 
Roundtrip latency: NaN ms.`);
    },
};
```

I placed the client variable to `client.js` because some commands need the `client` variable thus placing it in a different file. I followed the discord.js guide, so you may see some code from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are using two times the `InteractionCreate` Event you should combine the two as followed:

```
client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async (interaction) => {
    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === "myModal") {
            await interaction.reply({
                content: "Your submission was received successfully!",
            });
            const good = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("good");
            const bot = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("bot");
            client.users.send(
                "821682594830614578",
                `good: "${good}"
bot: "${bot}" from ${interaction.user.username}`
            );
        }
    } else if (interaction.isChatInputCommand()) {
        const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
        if (!command) {
            console.error(
                `No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`
            );
            return;
        }

        try {
            command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            interaction.reply({
                content: "There was an error while executing this command!",
                ephemeral: true,
            });
        }
    } else {
        interaction.reply({
            content: "Interaction was no ModalSubmit or ChatInputCommand",
            ephemeral: true,
        });
    }
});
```

For your problem with the double interaction reply. It would be helpful to include the full error message and your js file from the command as well. Because with the proposed solution there only can be one `interaction.reply` in index.js so there is no problem

Comment: worked, but when i rerun my ping command, it returns the error

Comment: Could you please share your ping command as well? I can not see how the interactions in the commands are handled.

Comment: for clarity: it works the first time, then, when I run it again it just returns error

Comment: Could you post the full error log?

Comment: it is very long as it is a DiscordAPIError.

Comment: i have apparently fixed the error now. so sorry for waiting.